# how i can align the icon's positon in ionic framework and it need to responsive too

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

How I can align the icon to the rightcorner position.

but it needs to be responsive too.

I have tried using header in ionic but the right alignment is not working properly.

```
<div class="bar bar-header" style="background-color:silver;">
  <span class="text-centre" style="color:white; position:relative; top:2px;">Hello,<b>UserName</b></span>
  <span class="title margin-align">
    <img src="logo.img" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></img>
  </span>
  <i class="ion-android-notifications" style="font-size:23px; padding: 1px 12px 0 480px;"></i>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By right corner position, do you mean you want it to be on the header bar's right corner side?

If so, any button/a tag after h1 div would be placed on the right side.

```
<div class="bar bar-header">
  <button class="button icon ion-navicon"></button>
  <h1 class="title">Header Buttons</h1>
  <button class="button">Edit</button>
</div>
```

If not, can you provide a codepen so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `position: absolute` on image span. Something like this:

```
<div class="bar bar-header" style="background-color:silver; position:relative">
  <span class="text-centre" style="color:white; position:relative; top:2px;">Hello,<b>UserName</b></span>
  <span class="title margin-align" style="position:absolute; right: 10px; top: 5px;">
    <img src="logo.img" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></img>
  </span>
  <i class="ion-android-notifications" style="font-size:23px; padding: 1px 12px 0 480px;"></i>  
</div>
```

You can also use `float: right`:

```
<div class="bar bar-header" style="background-color:silver;">
  <span class="text-centre" style="color:white; position:relative; top:2px;">Hello,<b>UserName</b></span>
  <span class="title margin-align" style="float:right">
    <img src="logo.img" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></img>
  </span>
  <i class="ion-android-notifications" style="font-size:23px; padding: 1px 12px 0 480px;"></i>  
</div>
```

I guess this might solve your problem of right aligning your image along with responsive design.